# Whats the best way to share real time data from an apple watch app to iphone app in watchOS4?

Tags: ios, performance, watchkit, watch, wcsession

I have been having trouble with the WCSession, it does get a message across but it is really slow it can take up to 10 seconds for me to receive the message on the iPhone app. So I was wondering if there is a better way these days to do this (I'm pretty new to Swift btw)

Answer (score 0):

Just use WatchConnectivity WCSession->sendMessage

[Offical Apple Doc Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615687-sendmessage)